# Change element content on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Attempt of trying to create to menu systems that changes content.

More simple secondary menu, keeps the secondary menu intact but still breaks the primary:

https://jsfiddle.net/ph3ng2fo/35/

You can see the first two tabs are fine, but "order" and "replacement filters" have no content.

---

Both sliding systems to display content, the secondary sliding content menu is nested in the primary systems Li, this breaks down both systems:

I just made 3 Fiddle so you can see what i am trying to do:

First here is a slide li element once span is clicked http://jsfiddle.net/3to0neLm/1

Second slide lie element once span is clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/feto4ymt/1

They both work fine. Now put second slide into one of the li's in the first slide (now it breaks down) : http://jsfiddle.net/ph3ng2fo/34

**SCRPIT**

```
//Slide Content
var TabbedContent = {
    current: {i:null, obj:null},
    init: function() {
        $(".tab_item").click(function() {
                $(".tab_item").removeClass("tab_item_color");
    $(this).addClass("tab_item_color");
            var $this = $(this);
            TabbedContent.slideContent($this);
        });
        TabbedContent.current.i = 0;
        TabbedContent.current.obj = $(".tabslider li").eq(0);
    },
    slideContent: function($obj) {
        var $container = $obj.closest(".tabbed_content"),        
            $contentContainer = $('.bodymainMaxS'),
            $tabslider = $contentContainer.find(".tabslider");
        var i = $obj.index() - 1;
        var $lis = $tabslider.find("li");
        $new = $lis.eq(i);
        if(i === TabbedContent.current.i) {
            return;
        }
        $lis.hide().filter($new.add(TabbedContent.current.obj)).show();
        var margin_1 = (i > TabbedContent.current.i) ? 0 : -$new.width();
        var margin_2 = (i < TabbedContent.current.i) ? 0 : -$new.width();
        $tabslider.stop().css({
            marginLeft: margin_1 + "px"
        }).animate({
            marginLeft: margin_2 + "px"
        }, 400);
        TabbedContent.current.i = i;
        TabbedContent.current.obj = $new;
    }
}
TabbedContent.init();

    $(".tab_item2").click(function() {
    $(".tab_item2").removeClass("tab_item_color2");
    $(this).addClass("tab_item_color2");
 $(".tabslider2 li").hide().eq($(this).index(".tab_item2")).show(); });
```

Comment: is it the eq. and index that is clashing between the two?